# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%1%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

Tags: java, spring

Friends, I have this problem and I can't find the solution, any suggestions?

```
@Repository(value = "TblagendalabRepository")
public interface TblagendalabRepository extends JpaRepository<Tblagendalab, Integer>{
    
     @Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Tblagendalab p WHERE p.tblagendalabPK.idExamen LIKE %:q%")
      List<Tblagendalab> findByExamenLab(@Param("q") Integer q);

}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/buscar")
    public String buscarExamen(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "buscar", required = false)Integer q, @RequestParam(value="idExamen", required = false) Integer idExamen) {

                        List<Tblagendalab> examenes = this.tblagendalabRepository.findByExamenLab(q);
            model.addAttribute("examenes", examenes);
            return "/views/agenda/agendar";

    }
```

Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblagendalab")
public class Tblagendalab implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected TblagendalabPK tblagendalabPK;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_examen", referencedColumnName = "id_examen", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tblexamen tblexamen;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idhora", referencedColumnName = "idhora", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tblhora tblhora;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_lab", referencedColumnName = "id_lab", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tbllab tbllab;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tblagendalab")
    private List<Tblreserva> tblreservaList;
```

Entities PK

```
@Embeddable
public class TblagendalabPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_examen")
    private int idExamen;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idhora")
    private int idhora;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_lab")
    private int idLab;
```

Output

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%1%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
```

I tried the solutions here on Stack Overflow, but they didn't work. I modified the @Param to String, int, the query directly from the Tblagendalab entitie etc.

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vOmM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d16s.png)

Comment: `LIKE '%' |:q|'%' ` or some kind of string concatenation.

Comment: I don't think so, because with another entity it works correctly with LIKE %:q% , but in this case, which is a many-to-many table, it gives me this problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand the concatenation problem, but in the debugger the value is 1. and in the url it shows the correct value which is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare an integer value with a string. no matter how you change the input `@Params` to any type, the problem is `%:q%` can not be used to compare for an integer. If you want to do the comparative that way, I think you must cast the value to a string before compare

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Tblagendalab p WHERE cast(p.tblagendalabPK.idExamen as string) LIKE '%:q%'")
List<Tblagendalab> findByExamenLab(@Param("q") Integer q);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about %%; 
When use jpa query sql, u must concat % with the parameter
The right sql would be:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Tblagendalab p WHERE p.tblagendalabPK.idExamen LIKE CONCAT('%',:q,'%')" , nativeQuery = true );
```